# how to assign the content to which a pointer point to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a char pointer points to an address of the memory and I need to get the content of that address and put it into an char array?

```
char *msg;

char cntnt[10];
```

msg is pointing to "mike" and I need to put this string into `cntnt[10]`.

I do like this

```
*cntnt = *msg;
```

when I do this, cntnt only get one letter 'm'.

please help....

Answer (score 3):

Use strcpy:

```
strcpy(cntnt, msg);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `strcpy` or `memcpy`.

```
len = strlen(msg);
if (len >= sizeof(cntnt))
    /* Bail out, not enough space. */

memcpy(cntnt, msg, len);
cntnt[len] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `memcpy` to copy `n` number of bytes from that pointer to the array:

```
char cntnt[10];
memcpy(cntnt, msg, 9);
```

using strcpy is recommended only if you have a null terminated string memory pointed by `msg` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

pointers and arrays are not equal. They are only similar in some ways. 
So, after your code you changed only one element of your array.

If you want to change the place where cntnt is localized, you should write

```
cntnt = msg;
```

If you want to copy the content of char  sequence to array, use strcpy, as Tudor said.
here is a nice explanation of the subject: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html